# multiple kafka topic input to logstash with different filter and codec

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I'm setting up an elk with kafka and want to send log through 2 kafka topic ( topic1 for windowslog and topic2 for wazuh log) to logstash with different codec and filter. I tryed with bellow input config for logstash but it doesn't

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9000"
    topics => ["windowslog", "system02"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json"
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
  }
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka-broker:9000"
    topics => ["wazuh-alerts"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}
```

and filter.conf file :

```
filter {
  if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "wazuh-alerts" {
    if [data][srcip] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][srcip]}" ]
    }
    }
    if [data][aws][sourceIPAddress] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][aws][sourceIPAddress]}" ]
      }
    }
    geoip {
      source => "@src_ip"
      target => "GeoLocation"
      fields => ["city_name", "country_name", "region_name", "location"]
    }
    date {
      match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "timestamp", "beat", "input_type", "tags", "count", "@version", "log", "offset", "type", "@src_ip", "host"]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use tags on each `input` and filter based on those tags.

For example:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka-broker:9000"
    topics => ["wazuh-alerts"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json_lines"
    tags => ["wazuh-alerts"]
  }
}
```

And in your filters and outputs you need a conditional based on that tag.

```
filter {
    if "wazuh-alerts" in [tags] {
        your filters
    }
}
output {
    if "wazuh-alerts" in [tags] {
        your output 
    }
}
```

Comment: please see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878952/how-to-integrating-wazuh-server-with-helk)