# How to integrating Wazuh Server with HELK

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana

I want to integrate Wazuh server with  [HELK](https://github.com/Cyb3rWard0g/HELK) but I can't do it and logstash cannot get any Wazuh alert from kafka or sending Wazuh alerts to Elasticsearch.
I create kafka topic with "wazuh-alerts" name and set my configuration in logstash config files . What's problem ?

In HELK , Logstash configuration placed on pipeline directory and it's contain below file :

```
0002-kafka-input.conf                                       1534-winevent-application-filter.conf        8801-meta-command_line-enrichment_and_additions-filter.conf
0003-attack-input.conf                                      1535-winevent-wmiactivity-filter.conf        8802-meta-powershell-enrichment_and_additions-filter.conf
0004-beats-input.conf                                       1541-winevent-process-name-split.conf        8901-fingerprints-command_line-filter.conf
0005-nxlog-winevent-syslog-tcp-input.conf                   1542-winevent-process-ids-conversions.conf   8902-fingerprints-powershell.conf
0098-all-filter.conf                                        1543-winevent-user-ids-conversions.conf      9950-winevent-sysmon-output.conf
0099-all-fingerprint-hash-filter.conf                       1544-winevent-cleanup-other.conf             9951-winevent-security-output.conf
0301-nxlog-winevent-to-json.conf                            1545-winevent-security-conversions.conf      9952-winevent-system-output.conf
1010-winevent-winlogbeats-filter.conf                       9953-winevent-application-output.conf
1050-nxlog-winevent-to-winlogbeats-merge-filter.conf        2511-winevent-powershell-filter.conf         9954-winevent-powershell-output.conf
1216-attack-filter.conf                                     2512-winevent-security-schtasks-filter.conf  9955-winevent-wmiactivity-output.conf
1500-winevent-cleanup-no-dashes-only-values-filter.conf     8012-dst-ip-cleanups-filter.conf             9956-attack-output.conf
1521-winevent-conversions-ip-conversions-basic-filter.conf  8013-src-ip-cleanups-filter.conf             9957-winevent-sysmon-join-output.conf
1522-winevent-cleanup-lowercasing-windows-filter.conf       8014-dst-nat-ip-cleanups-filter.conf         9958-osquery-output.conf
1523-winevent-process-name-filter.conf                      8015-src-nat-ip-cleanups-filter.conf         9959-winevent-codeintegrity-output.conf
1524-winevent-process-ids-filter.conf                       8112-dst-ip-filter.conf                      9960-winevent-bits-output.conf
1531-winevent-sysmon-filter.conf                            8113-src-ip-filter.conf                      9961-winevent-dns-client-output.conf
1532-winevent-security-filter.conf                          8114-dst-nat-ip-filter.conf                  9962-winevent-firewall-advanced-output.conf
1533-winevent-system-filter.conf                            8115-src-nat-ip-filter.conf
```

I changed 0002-kafka-input.conf file from :

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "helk-kafka-broker:9092"
    topics => ["winlogbeat", "SYSMON_JOIN","filebeat"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json"
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Throughput & Latency #############################
    fetch_min_bytes => "1"
    request_timeout_ms => "40000"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Durability #############################
    enable_auto_commit => "false"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Availability #############################
    connections_max_idle_ms => "540000"
    session_timeout_ms => "30000"
    max_poll_interval_ms => "300000"
    #############################
    max_poll_records => "500"
  }
}
```

to below for new kafka topic input that created for Wazuh alerts :

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "helk-kafka-broker:9092"
    topics => ["winlogbeat", "SYSMON_JOIN","filebeat"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json"
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    tags => [ "winlog-sysmon" ]
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Throughput & Latency #############################
    fetch_min_bytes => "1"
    request_timeout_ms => "40000"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Durability #############################
    enable_auto_commit => "false"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Availability #############################
    connections_max_idle_ms => "540000"
    session_timeout_ms => "30000"
    max_poll_interval_ms => "300000"
    #############################
    max_poll_records => "500"
  }
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "helk-kafka-broker:9092"
    topics => ["wazuh-alerts"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json_lines"
    tags => [ "wazuh-alerts" ]
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
  }
}
```

and I created 1546-wazuh-alerts-filter.conf file with below content for input filter :

```
filter {
  if "wazuh-alerts" in [tags]{
    if [data][srcip] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][srcip]}" ]
    }
    }
    if [data][aws][sourceIPAddress] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][aws][sourceIPAddress]}" ]
      }
    }
    geoip {
      source => "@src_ip"
      target => "GeoLocation"
      fields => ["city_name", "country_name", "region_name", "location"]
    }
    date {
      match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "timestamp", "beat", "input_type", "tags", "count", "@version", "log", "offset", "type", "@src_ip", "host"]
    }
  }
}
```

and 9963-wazuh-alerts-output.conf file for logstash output config :

```
output {
  if "wazuh-alerts" in [tags]{
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["helk-elasticsearch:9200"]
      index => "mitre-attack-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      user => 'elastic'
      #password => 'elasticpassword'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output has a conditional using the `tags` field, but you are removing it on your filters block, it doesn't work because the field does not exist when the event enters the output block.

Leave the `tags` field in your message and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I changed my configuration but it didn't work.

Comment: You removed the conditional on the `tags` filter and changed it to `[@metadata][kafka][topic]`, does this field exists? You will need to debug your pipeline, change the output to stdout, remove all the filters and add them one by one to see which one is not working.

Comment: Thanks . I should use conditional because there are several stream that have specific codec and filter. I red some article that declare if use "decorate_events => true" field in input config we can use "[@metadata][kafka][topic]" field on filter and output configuration. I'm really confused .Can you tell me which field should add to config files ?

Comment: Try to use the `tags` field in your conditional, but don't remove it before your output, the problem with your original configuration is that you were removing the `tags` field before a conditional based on that field.

Comment: Thanks . I used 'if "wazuh-alerts" in [tags]' in filter configuration because in this case I have multiple input and I need choose specific input for filtering configuration. If I don't use wazuh-alert tags in filter configuration this filter execute on all input. how can I handle it ?

Comment: Sorry I don't see removed_filed section . I hope this work fix it

Comment: I changed my configuration and delete "tags" from removed_fileld but nothing changed and not working yet . after that I delete filter config file and used only input and output config for testing purpose . I set tags=> wazuh-log in input and if "wazuh-log" in [tags] in output but nothing sent to elasticsearch or wrote to file ( based on output config ) . How can I resolve this problem and how can I trace input stream to logstash ( from kafka ) ?

Comment: Do you have data in Kafka? If you do not filter by tags do you have any output? You will need to debug each step, do not filter by tags and see if you have any data, then look at your data to see what went wrong when you started to filter. If you paste some output example, it helps to see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I changed logstash configuration to this :

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "helk-kafka-broker:9092"
    topics => ["winlogbeat", "SYSMON_JOIN","filebeat"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json"
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Throughput & Latency #############################
    fetch_min_bytes => "1"
    request_timeout_ms => "40000"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Durability #############################
    enable_auto_commit => "false"
    ############################# HELK Optimizing Availability #############################
    connections_max_idle_ms => "540000"
    session_timeout_ms => "30000"
    max_poll_interval_ms => "300000"
    #############################
    max_poll_records => "500"
  }
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "helk-kafka-broker:9092"
    topics => ["wazuh-alerts"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "json_lines"
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
  }
}
```

```
filter {
  if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "wazuh-alerts" {
    if [data][srcip] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][srcip]}" ]
    }
    }
    if [data][aws][sourceIPAddress] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "@src_ip", "%{[data][aws][sourceIPAddress]}" ]
      }
    }
    geoip {
      source => "@src_ip"
      target => "GeoLocation"
      fields => ["city_name", "country_name", "region_name", "location"]
    }
    date {
      match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "timestamp", "beat", "input_type", "tags", "count", "@version", "log", "offset", "type", "@src_ip", "host"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
output {
  if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "wazuh-alerts" {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/greatlog.log"
    }
  }
}
```

Please if possible see HELK configuration at [here](https://github.com/Cyb3rWard0g/HELK/tree/master/docker/helk-logstash/pipeline) and wazuh logstash config at [here](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/blob/master/extensions/logstash/01-wazuh-remote.conf)
. I should use kafka topic for sendig wazuh alerts log to Helk because HELK using kafka ( I sent wazuh alerts log with filebeat to kafka ). Now how can I change HELK Configuration to do it ?
Thanks